# Puzzling Enumerable.Cast InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, exception

The following throws an `InvalidCastException`.

```
IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int>() { 1 };
IEnumerable<long> castedList = list.Cast<long>();
Console.WriteLine(castedList.First());
```

Why?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: I’m amazed that none of the answers actually answers the question *why*. The answer is because conversion from int to long **is not a cast**. It’s a *conversion*. It is unfortunate that C# uses the same syntax for both of those, as it only confuses people (apparently). You also can’t use `.Cast<T>()` to invoke a custom-defined explicit conversion operator because that’s also not a cast.

Comment: @Timwi: Sorry, but no. The issue is boxing and that `(long)o` where `o` is a boxed `int` will throw. If somehow boxing were avoided here this would not throw. Additionally, cast is a language construct and conversion is the runtime behavior invoked by that construct.

Comment: You can’t use `.Cast<T>` to convert between different integer types (`new int[] { 1 }.Cast<long>()` throws), and you also can’t use it to invoke explicit conversion operators (`new XAttribute[] { new XAttribute("X", "Y") }.Cast<string>()` throws even though `(string) new XAttribute("X", "Y")` doesn’t). Even if boxing explains the former (which it doesn’t — there is no *need* for boxing there; if the internal implementation uses it, it does so gratuitously), it doesn’t explain the latter (which is all reference types).

Comment: Furthermore, take care when you use the word “language construct” in two different meanings. There is certainly the cast *syntax*, which is defined by the language and which is the same for all three operations, but the language specification also defines the *semantics* of that syntax, and it clearly states that “numeric conversions”, “implicit/explicit conversion operators” and “reference conversions” (casts) are three separate operations.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That's very odd! There's a blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ed_maurer/archive/2008/02/16/breaking-change-in-linq-queries-using-explicitly-typed-range-variables.aspx) that describes how the behaviour of `Cast<T>()` was changed between .NET 3.5 and .NET 3.5 SP1, but it still doesn't explain the InvalidCastException, which you even get if you rewrite your code thus:

```
var list = new[] { 1 };
var castedList = from long l in list select l;
Console.WriteLine(castedList.First());
```

Obviously you can work around it by doing the cast yourself

```
var castedList = list.Select(i => (long)i);
```

This works, but it doesn't explain the error in the first place. I tried casting the list to short and float and those threw the same exception.

**Edit**

That blog post does explain why it doesn't work!

`Cast<T>()` is an extension method on `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. That means that by the time each value gets to the point where it's being cast, it has already been boxed back into a System.Object. In essence it's trying to do this:

```
int i = 1;
object o = i;
long l = (long)o;
```

This code throws the InvalidCastException you're getting. If you try to cast an int directly to a long you're fine, but casting a boxed int back to a long doesn't work.

Certainly an oddity!

Comment: +1 - I had this exact issue and read the blog and couldn't work it out. Your edit cleared it up. Great!

Comment: There is nothing odd about it at all. `.Cast<T>` does a **cast**. A conversion from int to long **is not a cast**. It is a shame that C# chose to use the same syntax for different operations.

Comment: @Timwi: Sorry, but no. See my comment to your comment above.

Comment: @Jason: Sorry, but yes. It is a shame that you would respond so aggressively when you don’t understand the issue. You didn’t even address my comment about explicit conversion operators.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering if they can write their own `Cast<T>` method to "fix" this, see my recent answer.

Comment: `Enumerable.Cast` treats everything as `System.Object`(because the input-sequence is not generic but `IEnumerable`), so boxes it if it's a value type. Here's the explanation why C# doesn't allow to cast a boxed value type to a different type which the unboxed value could have been cast to: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/

Answer (score 29):

Enumerable.Cast method is defined as following:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(
    this IEnumerable source
)
```

And there is no information about initial type of IEnumerable's items, so I think each of your ints is initially converted to System.Object via boxing and then it's tried to be unboxed into long variable and this is incorrect.

Similar code to reproduce this:

```
int i = 1;
object o = i; // boxing
long l = (long)o; // unboxing, incorrect
// long l = (int)o; // this will work
```

So solution for your problem will be:

```
ints.Select(i => (long)i)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm at it again!
Here's the solution to all your `List<T>` and `Enumerable<T>` conversion problems.
~150 lines of code
Just be sure to define at least one explicit or implicit conversion operator for the input/output types involved (if one does not exist), as you should be doing anyway!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace System.Collections.Generic //purposely in same namespace as List<T>,IEnumerable<T>, so extension methods are available with them
{
    public static class Enumerable
    {
        public static List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput>( this IEnumerable<TInput> input ) {
            return BuildConvertedList<TInput,TOutput>( input, GetConverterDelegate<TInput,TOutput>() );
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TOutput> ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput>( this IEnumerable<TInput> input, bool lazy ) {
            if (lazy) return new LazyConverter<TInput,TOutput>( input, GetConverterDelegate<TInput,TOutput>() );
            return BuildConvertedList<TInput,TOutput>( input, GetConverterDelegate<TInput,TOutput>() );
        }

        public static List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput>( this IEnumerable<TInput> input, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter ) {
            return BuildConvertedList<TInput,TOutput>( input, converter );
        }

        public static List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>( this List<TInput> input ) {
            Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter = GetConverterDelegate<TInput,TOutput>();
            return input.ConvertAll<TOutput>( converter );
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TOutput> ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>( this List<TInput> input, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter, bool lazy ) {
            if (lazy) return new LazyConverter<TInput, TOutput>( input, converter );
            return input.ConvertAll<TOutput>( converter );
        }

        public static List<TOutput> ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>( this List<TInput> input, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter ) {
            return input.ConvertAll<TOutput>( converter );
        }

        //Used to manually build converted list when input is IEnumerable, since it doesn't have the ConvertAll method like the List does
        private static List<TOutput> BuildConvertedList<TInput,TOutput>( IEnumerable<TInput> input, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter ){
            List<TOutput> output = new List<TOutput>();
            foreach (TInput input_item in input)
                output.Add( converter( input_item ) );
            return output;
        }

        private sealed class LazyConverter<TInput, TOutput>: IEnumerable<TOutput>, IEnumerator<TOutput>
        {
            private readonly IEnumerable<TInput> input;
            private readonly Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter;
            private readonly IEnumerator<TInput> input_enumerator;

            public LazyConverter( IEnumerable<TInput> input, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter )
            {
                this.input = input;
                this.converter = converter;
                this.input_enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
            }

            public IEnumerator<TOutput> GetEnumerator() {return this;} //IEnumerable<TOutput> Member
            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {return this;} //IEnumerable Member
            public void Dispose() {input_enumerator.Dispose();} //IDisposable Member
            public TOutput Current {get {return converter.Invoke( input_enumerator.Current );}} //IEnumerator<TOutput> Member
            object IEnumerator.Current {get {return Current;}} //IEnumerator Member
            public bool MoveNext() {return input_enumerator.MoveNext();} //IEnumerator Member
            public void Reset() {input_enumerator.Reset();} //IEnumerator Member
        }

        private sealed class TypeConversionPair: IEquatable<TypeConversionPair>
        {
            public readonly Type source_type;
            public readonly Type target_type;
            private readonly int hashcode;

            public TypeConversionPair( Type source_type, Type target_type ) {
                this.source_type = source_type;
                this.target_type = target_type;
                //precalc/store hash, since object is immutable; add one to source hash so reversing the source and target still produces unique hash
                hashcode = (source_type.GetHashCode() + 1) ^ target_type.GetHashCode();
            }

            public static bool operator ==( TypeConversionPair x, TypeConversionPair y ) {
                if ((object)x != null) return x.Equals( y );
                if ((object)y != null) return y.Equals( x );
                return true; //x and y are both null, cast to object above ensures reference equality comparison
            }

            public static bool operator !=( TypeConversionPair x, TypeConversionPair y ) {
                if ((object)x != null) return !x.Equals( y );
                if ((object)y != null) return !y.Equals( x );
                return false; //x and y are both null, cast to object above ensures reference equality comparison
            }

            //TypeConversionPairs are equal when their source and target types are equal
            public bool Equals( TypeConversionPair other ) {
                if ((object)other == null) return false; //cast to object ensures reference equality comparison
                return source_type == other.source_type && target_type == other.target_type;
            }

            public override bool Equals( object obj ) {
                TypeConversionPair other = obj as TypeConversionPair;
                if ((object)other != null) return Equals( other ); //call IEqualityComparer<TypeConversionPair> implementation if obj type is TypeConversionPair
                return false; //obj is null or is not of type TypeConversionPair; Equals shall not throw errors!
            }

            public override int GetHashCode() {return hashcode;} //assigned in constructor; object is immutable
        }

        private static readonly Dictionary<TypeConversionPair,Delegate> conversion_op_cache = new Dictionary<TypeConversionPair,Delegate>();

        //Uses reflection to find and create a Converter<TInput, TOutput> delegate for the given types.
        //Once a delegate is obtained, it is cached, so further requests for the delegate do not use reflection*
        //(*the typeof operator is used twice to look up the type pairs in the cache)
        public static Converter<TInput, TOutput> GetConverterDelegate<TInput, TOutput>()
        {
            Delegate converter;
            TypeConversionPair type_pair = new TypeConversionPair( typeof(TInput), typeof(TOutput) );

            //Attempt to quickly find a cached conversion delegate.
            lock (conversion_op_cache) //synchronize with concurrent calls to Add
                if (conversion_op_cache.TryGetValue( type_pair, out converter ))
                    return (Converter<TInput, TOutput>)converter;

            //Get potential conversion operators (target-type methods are ordered first)
            MethodInfo[][] conversion_op_sets = new MethodInfo[2][] {
                type_pair.target_type.GetMethods( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy ),
                type_pair.source_type.GetMethods( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy )
            };

            //Find appropriate conversion operator,
            //favoring operators on target type in case functionally equivalent operators exist,
            //since the target type's conversion operator may have access to an appropriate constructor
            //or a common instance cache (i.e. immutable objects may be cached and reused).
            for (int s = 0; s < conversion_op_sets.Length; s++) {
                MethodInfo[] conversion_ops = conversion_op_sets[s];
                for (int m = 0; m < conversion_ops.Length; m++)
                {
                    MethodInfo mi = conversion_ops[m];
                    if ((mi.Name == "op_Explicit" || mi.Name == "op_Implicit") && 
                        mi.ReturnType == type_pair.target_type &&
                        mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom( type_pair.source_type )) //Assuming op_Explicit and op_Implicit always have exactly one parameter.
                    {
                        converter = Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof(Converter<TInput, TOutput>), mi );
                        lock (conversion_op_cache) //synchronize with concurrent calls to TryGetValue
                            conversion_op_cache.Add( type_pair, converter ); //Cache the conversion operator reference for future use.
                        return (Converter<TInput, TOutput>)converter;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (TInput x) => ((TOutput)Convert.ChangeType( x, typeof(TOutput) )); //this works well in the absence of conversion operators for types that implement IConvertible
            //throw new InvalidCastException( "Could not find conversion operator to convert " + type_pair.source_type.FullName + " to " + type_pair.target_type.FullName + "." );
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample use:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>(new string[] { "abcde", "abcd", "abc"/*will break length constraint*/, "ab", "a" });
            //Uncomment line below to see non-lazy behavior.  All items converted before method returns, and will fail on third item, which breaks the length constraint.
            //List<ConstrainedString> constrained_list = list.ConvertAll<string,ConstrainedString>();
            IEnumerable<ConstrainedString> constrained_list = list.ConvertAll<string,ConstrainedString>( true ); //lazy conversion; conversion is not attempted until that item is read
            foreach (ConstrainedString constrained_string in constrained_list) //will not fail until the third list item is read/converted
                System.Console.WriteLine( constrained_string.ToString() );
        }   

        public class ConstrainedString
        {
            private readonly string value;
            public ConstrainedString( string value ){this.value = Constrain(value);}
            public string Constrain( string value ) {
                if (value.Length > 3) return value;
                throw new ArgumentException("String length must be > 3!");
            }
            public static explicit operator ConstrainedString( string value ){return new ConstrainedString( value );}
            public override string ToString() {return value;}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... interesting puzzle. All the more interesting given that I just ran it in Visual Studio 2008 and it *didn't* throw at all.

I'm not using Service Pack 1, and you might be, so that could be the issue. I know there were some "performance enhancements" in .Cast() in the SP1 release that could be causing the issue. Some reading:

[Blog Entry 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/ed_maurer/archive/2008/02/16/breaking-change-in-linq-queries-using-explicitly-typed-range-variables.aspx)

[Blog Entry 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/08/10/net-fx-3-5-sp1-two-perf-improvements-linq-to-objects-and-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Comment: Yes, it was "fixed" to use a cast rather than Convert as of SP1 (as per the first blog post you linked to).

Comment: Links to answers are no good as the links tend to rot, much as these did...

Answer (score 2):

I wish they could have done something intelligent, like using any implicit or explicit cast operators defined for the type.  The current behavior and inconsistency is unacceptable.  Absolutely useless in its current condition.

After realizing that `Cast<Type>` was throwing an exception instead of using the cast operators that I defined for the type, I became irritated and found this thread.  If it's defined for `IEnumerable`, why wouldn't they just implement it to use reflection to get the type of object, get the target type, discover any available static conversion operators, and find an appropriate one to do the cast.  It could cast a heterogeneous `IEnumerable` into an `IEnumerable<T>`.

The following implementation is a working idea...

```
public static class EnumerableMinusWTF
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult,TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        Type source_type = typeof(TSource);
        Type target_type = typeof(TResult);

        List<MethodInfo> methods = new List<MethodInfo>();
        methods.AddRange( target_type.GetMethods( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public ) ); //target methods will be favored in the search
        methods.AddRange( source_type.GetMethods( BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public ) );
        MethodInfo op_Explicit = FindExplicitConverstion(source_type, target_type, methods );

        List<TResult> results = new List<TResult>();
        foreach (TSource source_item in source)
            results.Add((TResult)op_Explicit.Invoke(null, new object[] { source_item }));
        return results;
    }

    public static MethodInfo FindExplicitConverstion(Type source_type, Type target_type, List<MethodInfo> methods)
    {
        foreach (MethodInfo mi in methods)
        {
            if (mi.Name == "op_Explicit") //will return target and take one parameter
                if (mi.ReturnType == target_type)
                    if (mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == source_type)
                        return mi;
        }
        throw new InvalidCastException( "Could not find conversion operator to convert " + source_type.FullName + " to " + target_type.FullName + "." );
    }
}
```

I can then call this code successfully:

```
    //LessonID inherits RegexConstrainedString, and has explicit conversion operator defined to convert string to LessonID
List<string> lessons = new List<String>(new string[] {"l001,l002"});
IEnumerable<LessonID> constrained_lessons = lessons.Cast<LessonID, string>();
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't help at all for conversions like that in the original question (int to long), which are language defined.

Comment: Indeed.  I'm getting more irritated with .net and c#, because there are so many ways to convert things, none of which take the obvious route of applying defined explicit conversion operators.  Furthermore, reflection seems to be the only way to apply explicit conversion operators generically.

Answer (score 2):

**Here are some things to think about...**

1. Do you want to cast or convert?
2. Do you want the result as a `List<T>` or an `IEnumerable<T>`.
3. If the result is an `IEnumerable<T>`, do you want the cast/convert to be applied lazily (i.e. the cast/convert will not actually occur until the iterator reaches each element)?

**Useful distinction between cast/convert, since a casting operator often involves constructing a new object, and could be considered a conversion:**
"Cast" implementations should automatically apply conversion operators defined for the types involved; *a new object may or may not be constructed*.
"Convert" implementations should allow one to specify a `System.Converter<TInput,TOutput>` delegate.

**Potential method headers:**

```
List<TOutput> Cast<TInput,TOutput>(IEnumerable<TInput> input);
List<TOutput> Convert<TInput,TOutput>(IEnumerable<TInput> input, Converter<TInput,TOutput> converter);
IEnumerable<TOutput> Cast<TInput,TOutput>(IEnumerable<TInput> input);
IEnumerable<TOutput> Convert<TInput,TOutput>(IEnumerable<TInput> input, Converter<TInput,TOutput> converter);
```

**Problematic "Cast" implementations using existing framework; suppose you pass as input a `List<string>`, that you want to convert with any of the previous methods.**

```
//Select can return only a lazy read-only iterator; also fails to use existing explicit cast operator, because such a cast isn't possible in c# for a generic type parameter (so says VS2008)
list.Select<TInput,TOutput>( (TInput x) => (TOutput)x );
//Cast fails, unless TOutput has an explicit conversion operator defined for 'object' to 'TOutput'; this confusion is what lead to this topic in the first place
list.Cast<TOuput>();
```

**Problematic "Convert" implementations**

```
//Again, the cast to a generic type parameter not possible in c#; also, this requires a List<T> as input instead of just an IEnumerable<T>.
list.ConvertAll<TOutput>( new Converter<TInput,TOuput>( (TInput x) => (TOutput)x ) );
//This would be nice, except reflection is used, and must be used since c# hides the method name for explicit operators "op_Explicit", making it difficult to obtain a delegate any other way.
list.ConvertAll<TOutput>(
    (Converter<TInput,TOutput>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(Converter<TInput,TOutput>),
        typeof(TOutput).GetMethod( "op_Explicit", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public )
    )
);
```

**Summary:**
Cast/Convert methods should involve defined explicit conversion operators, or allow one to specify a conversion delegate.  C#'s language specification for conversion operators -- specifically their lack of a method name -- makes it difficult to obtain a delegate except through reflection.  The alternative is to encapsulate or replicate the conversion code, increasing the (maintenance) complexity of your code unnecessarily, since really, *possible/allowed* conversions are implicit in the presence or absence of conversion operators, and should be handled by the compiler.  We should not have to manually search for cryptically-named definitions (e.g. "op_Explicit") of appropriate conversion operators with reflection at **RUN TIME** on the types involved.  Furthermore, Cast/Convert methods for bulk/list conversions using explicit conversion operators should really be a framework feature, and with `List.ConvertAll<T>`, they are... except the language spec makes it hard to get a delegate for the conversion operators efficiently!!!

Comment: Under "Problematic convert implementations", I use typeof(TOutput) to get the conversion operator's MethodInfo, but it may be defined on typeof(TInput) or niether, so the actual logic for this ideal approach would be more complex. My whole point is, it shouldn't be that complex nor done at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the sane thing to do is to use `Select(i => (long)i)` and that's what I would recommend for conversions between built-in value types and for user-defined conversion.

But just as a **curious** remark, since .NET 4 it is possible to make your own extension method that also works with these kinds of conversions. But it requires that you're willing to use the `dynamic` keyword. It goes simply like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> CastSuper<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    foreach (var s in source)
        yield return (TResult)(dynamic)s;
}
```

As I said, works with integral conversions (narrowing or widening conversions), numerical conversions to/from/between floating-point types, and conversion "methods" of the kinds `implicit operator` and `explicit operator`.

And of course it still works with the good old reference conversions and unboxing conversions like the original `System.Enumerable.Cast<TResult>`.

Comment: Expect a performance penalty if you use `dynamic` since the analysis of which conversion to use, will have to be done run-time. That's why `.Select(i => (long)i)` is recommended.