# Convert byte array to short array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm currently reading a file and wanted to be able to convert the array of bytes obtained from the file into a short array.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to convert 1 byte to 1 short, or 2 bytes to 1 short?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possibility is using [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

```
byte[] bytes;
var shorts = bytes.Select(b => (short)b).ToArray();
```

Another is to use [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx):

```
byte[] bytes;
var shorts = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, b => (short)b);
```

Comment: Your original suggestion (before you added the second one later on) is rather inefficient

Comment: Another option would be bytes.Cast<short>().ToArray();

Comment: Actually, this results in a InvalidCastException. The short explanation is that this code implicitly causes an boxed byte to be unboxed to a short which is not a valid unboxing operation. For details, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception.

Comment: When I used var shorts[] = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, b => (short)b); I got each byte converted to a short not each pair of bytes converted.

Answer (score 67):

Use [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx).

Create the short array at half the size of the byte array, and copy the byte data in:

```
short[] sdata = new short[(int)Math.Ceiling(data.Length / 2)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, sdata, 0, data.Length);
```

It is the fastest method by far.

Comment: The solution i don't deserve, but the one i need right now!

Comment: Thanks! Great answer but I had to change the code slightly to: short[] sdata = new short[(int)Math.Ceiling(data.Length / 2.0)];. Otherwise, I would have gotten the following error: "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Ceiling(decimal)' and 'Math.Ceiling(double)' "

Answer (score 6):

A shorthard is a compound of two bytes. If you are writing all the shorts to the file as true shorts then those conversions are wrong. You must use two bytes to get the true short value, using something like:

```
short s = (short)(bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8))
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  You have to do it like this to make it work:
    short s = (short)((bytes[0] << 8) | bytes[1]);

Comment: Assuming little endian, this should be: short s = (short)(bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8))

Answer (score 2):

```
short value = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, index);
```

Comment: This one uses _index_ as LSB and _index+1_ as MSB. Is there one that follows BigEndian to use _index_ as the MSB?

Comment: Did you even read the question? It is about byte[] to short[] not short.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, but I would have expected another aproach to this question.
When converting a sequence of bytes into a sequence of shorts, i would have it done like @Peter did

```
short s = (short)(bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8))
```

or

```
short s = (short)((bytes[0] << 8) | bytes[1])
```

depending on endianess of the bytes in the file.

But the OP didnt mention his usage of the shorts or the definition of the shorts in the file.
In his case it would make no sense to convert the byte array to a short array, because it would take twice as much memory, and i doubt if a byte would be needed to be converted to a short when used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
 short[] wordArray = Array.ConvertAll(byteArray, (b) => (short)b);
```

Comment: In my opinion, this would convert every byte into a short, which might not be the expected result als two bytes would represent a short ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```
byte[] bytes;
var shorts = bytes.Select(n => System.Convert.ToInt16(n)).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's extremely inefficient: Calling convert.ToInt16() for every element, storing it in a temporary list, and then copying it to an new array.

Comment: yes, it is inefficient. I'm thinking that it's safer, tho, then casting.

Comment: Safer than casting? A cast of byte to short always works. It can never throw an exception