# Casting a boxed value

Tags: c#, casting

Why can't an `int` that's been boxed be directly cast to `double`?

```
object o = 12;
double d = (double)o;
```

That throw an invalid cast exception.  Instead it seems it has to first be cast as an `int`, and then on to `double`.

```
object o = 12;
double d = (double)(int)o;
```

I'm sure the simple answer is "because that's how boxing works" but I'm hoping someone might shed a bit of light here.

Comment: See: [Representation and Identity - Fabulous Adventures In Coding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx)

Comment: @Ani - Put that as an answer, and I'll upvote it in a second!

Comment: Ditto - ani - looks like the right answer to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this question from earlier today: [Why am I getting InvalidCastException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309436/why-am-i-getting-invalidcastexception)

> Unboxing operations only succeed if the target type is exactly the same as the original type that was boxed, so an exception is thrown. [This link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) that John Leidegren provided explains in detail.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know the original type at compile-time:

```
object o = 12;
double d = (double)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(double));
```