# C# int- or object-to-double casting error explanation

Tags: c#, casting, int, double

The below code fails at the last assignment:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 5;
    object b = 5;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert( a is int && b is int );

    double x = (double)a;
    double y = (double)b;
}
```

If both a and b are `int`, what is the cause of this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a boxed value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312731/casting-a-boxed-value)

Answer (score 25):

This is an extremely frequently asked question. See https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/ for an explanation.

---

Snippet:

> I get a fair number of questions about the C# cast operator. The most frequent question I get is:
>
> ```
> short sss = 123;
> object ooo = sss;            // Box the short.
> int iii = (int) sss;         // Perfectly legal.
> int jjj = (int) (short) ooo; // Perfectly legal
> int kkk = (int) ooo;         // Invalid cast exception?! Why?
> ```
>
> Why? Because a boxed `T` can only be unboxed to `T`. (*) Once it is unboxed, it’s just a value that can be cast as usual, so the double cast works just fine.
>
> (*) Or `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 17):

Unboxing requires the exact type - you can do this instead:

```
double y = (double)(int)b;
```

Answer (score 7):

This is one of the rare cases where `System.Convert` comes in handy. You can use `System.Convert.ToDouble(obj)` to knock it out if you don't know beforehand that it will be `int`.

Comment: I would suggest this as the solution since forcing a cast directly might cause precision lost.

Answer (score 3):

Implicit casting is a compile-time operation. It's not possible for `b` of type `object`.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is an `int`, but `b` is a reference to an object that is an `int` - it is what is called a boxed int. They are two different things, hence the different behaviors.