# Why can't an object which holds a float value be cast to double?

Tags: c#, casting

If a float is assigned to a double, it accepts it, but if the float is first assigned to an object and then cast to double, it gives an InvalidCastException.

Can someone please clarify this?

```cs
float f = 12.4f;
double d = f;//this is ok

//but if f is assigned to object
object o = f;
double d1 = (double)o;//doesn't work, (System.InvalidCastException) 

double d2 = (float)o;//this works
```

Comment: Check the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387195/c-sharp-int-or-object-to-double-casting-error-explanation)

Comment: Thanks @martijn-van-put . The link helps. I understand that "Boxed T can only be unboxed to T".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Implicit numeric conversion**

```
float f = 12.4f;
double d = f;//this is ok
```

---

**Unboxing conversion**

```
object o = f;
double d1 = (double)o;//doesn't work, (System.InvalidCastException)
```

*An unboxing operation to a non_nullable_value_type consists of first checking that the object instance is a boxed value of the given non_nullable_value_type, and then copying the value out of the instance.*

In other words it checks if `o` is boxed from `double`, obviously not in this case.

---

More about conversions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions).

Comment: yes now i understand that while unboxing, its checks boxed type first. Thanks :)

Comment: Nitpick: the implicit conversion from `float` to `double` cannot cause data loss, since `double` has higher precision -- every `float` has an exact representation as a `double`. The number may appear to be different when it's formatted for display in base 10, but that's not the same thing as data loss.

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually you are right. Only explicit conversion could cause data loss... tnx

Comment: Stop editing your posts to bump them to the front page.