# What is the proper way to get an int from a float?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

I came across a problem and I think I have the solution but cannot find anyone to tell me if I am right or wrong? See sample in C# below:

```
public void Test(float number)
{
   object myObj = number;

  //Here is where I don't know what the correct way to do this is?
  // int newNumber = (int)myObj;
  // int newNumber = (int)(float)myObj;
 // int newNumber = (int)(double)myObj;
}
```

The result has to ensure no type exceptions occur. Any idea's guys?

Answer (score 1):

The second option is the right one.

First, you [unbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) your value by casting it to the exact type that was originally boxed (i.e. `float`).
And then you convert `float` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of boxed value is `float`, you need to cast it to `float` first because it needs to be unboxed:

```
int newNumber = (int)(float)myObj;
```

You can find more information from these questions if you wonder the reason of *double* cast:

- [Casting a boxed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312731/casting-a-boxed-value?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Why am I getting InvalidCastException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309436/why-am-i-getting-invalidcastexception)

Comment: Oh I guess that's where I was confused. I thought since it originally started out as a float object and a float can be casted to a int I could simply do (int)myObject.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try each...

```
//int newNumber = (int)myObj;
//InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

int newNumber = (int)(float)myObj; // works! newNumber is 2

//int newNumber = (int)(double)myObj;
//InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

When you have such a [boxed numeric value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) and wish to convert it with casting, you must first cast it to the *exact* type (in this case, `float`) before converting it to a compatible type (in this case, `int`).

If you don't know ahead of time that it's a `float`, but you do know it can be converted to `int`, you should use [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will work whether `myObj` is a `float`, `double`, etc.

```
int newNumber = Convert.ToInt32(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your test you don't know type of boxed value then **I'd avoid any double casting** (because for first one you'll always **need to know exact type**).

There is a class to work with conversion, let's try to use it:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(myObj, null);
```

Actually that's pretty different from plain casting, it'll perform something like this:

```
int number = ((IConvertible)myObj).ToInt32(null);
```

Difference is how **rounding is performed**. Cast will truncate your number (so 1.7 will become 1) while conversion will perform a rounding (so 1.7 will become 2).

If you're aware it's a floating point number (but you *don't know* if `double` or `float`) then I'd suggest to first convert to `double` then cast:

```
int number = (int)Convert.ToDouble(myObj, null);
```

See also my answer about [difference between casting and conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15395832/1207195).