# WrapPanel ItemWidth & ItemHeight MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding, wrappanel

I simply want to use `MultiBinding` for a `WrapPanel`'s `ItemHeight` & `ItemWidth`. The code is like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SensorHeightCalculator x:Key="HeightCalculator"/>
    <local:SensorWidthCalculator x:Key="WidthCalculator"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Border x:Name="sensorPanelBorder" BorderBrush="#FFD5DFE5" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,9,2,2" CornerRadius="3">
    <ListView x:Name="sensorPanel" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SensorControls}}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel x:Name="sensorWrapPanel" IsItemsHost="True">
                    <WrapPanel.ItemHeight>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HeightCalculator}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding ElementName="sensorPanelBorder" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="sensorPanelBorder" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="sensorPanel" Path="Items.Count"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </WrapPanel.ItemHeight>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Border>
```

But it throws exceptions and does not render.
I also tried to do this in code-behind but that didn't work either.

The actual problem is that I need to bind the items of `WrapPanel` to a `CollectionViewSource`, and therefore, as I read online, I have to use the `WrapPanel` inside a `ListView` (like above). Before that, I filled the `WrapPanel` manually I had a method which I was used to use to calculate the `ItemHeight` and `ItemWidth` of the `WrapPanel` and assign to that. But now that the `WrapPanel` is inside the `ListView`, it's not accessible in code-behind and hence I decided to use the `Multibinding`.

The Source of SensorHeightCalculator:

```
public class SensorHeightCalculator : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double H = (double)values[0];
            double W = (double)values[1];
            double N = (double)values[2];
            if (N > 0)
            {
                double k = 7.0 / 6.0;
                double c = N;
                double r = 1;
                double ah, aw, a, b;
                do
                {
                    aw = (W - 2) / c;
                    ah = k * aw;
                    if (Math.Floor(H / ah) <= r) break;
                    else
                    {
                        r++;
                        c = c - Math.Floor(c / r);
                    }
                } while (r <= N);
                a = Math.Min(aw, H / (k * r));
                b = k * a;
                return b - 10;
            }
            else
                return 300;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return default(object[]);
        }
    }
```

The exception and full stack trace of that:

Exception: InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Stack trace:

at AvaPa.SensorHeightCalculator.Convert(Object[] values, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.TransferValue()
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.Transfer()
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.UpdateTarget(Boolean includeInnerBindings)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachToContext(Boolean lastChance)
   at System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachOverride(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnAttach(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetInstanceValue(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feChild, FrameworkContentElement fceChild, Int32 childIndex, DependencyProperty dp, Int32 i, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValueHelper(UncommonField`1 dataField, ItemStructList`1& valueLookupList, DependencyProperty dp, DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, Boolean styleLookup, EffectiveValueEntry& entry, ValueLookupType& sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValue(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, Int32 childIndex, FrameworkObject child, DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, EffectiveValueEntry& entry, ValueLookupType& sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetValueFromTemplatedParent(DependencyObject container, Int32 childIndex, FrameworkObject child, DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplatedParentValue(DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, DependencyProperty dp, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplateNode(DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, Boolean isDetach, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplate(DependencyObject container, Object currentObject)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.HandleBeforeProperties(Object createdObject, DependencyObject& rootObject, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feContainer, INameScope nameScope)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.<>c__DisplayClass45_0.b__2(Object sender, XamlObjectEventArgs args)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.OnBeforeProperties(Object value)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(XamlMember property)
   at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: "But it throws exceptions" - what exception? Recommended reading - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist.

Comment: This is the exception, but I think does not really help:

InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Please, read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B, then add full stack trace of that exception to your question (not as comment). Also, this exception probably happens in `local:SensorHeightCalculator`, so its source code should be added as well.

Comment: @EugenePodskal I'm pretty sure that the exception has nothing to do with the SensorHeightCalculator, but I add that if you think so

Comment: That stack trace seems to disagree with you - `at AvaPa.SensorHeightCalculator.Convert`

Comment: @EugenePodskal Please explain the problem if you find out. I'm really stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting InvalidCastException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309436/why-am-i-getting-invalidcastexception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double N = (double)values[2];
```

is an invalid cast when the third binding in the MultiBinding binds to an integer:

```
<Binding ... Path="Items.Count"/>
```

So cast to an integer

```
var N = (int)values[2];
```

---

You should also make sure that the converter always returns a double, so replace

```
return 300;
```

with

```
return 300d;
```

Comment: Besides that, `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` on the MutliBinding doesn't make sense.

Comment: So you mean that I have to cast that to `integer`?
And remove the `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`?

Comment: Sure, that's what I mean.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the problem :-)