# Converting int[] to short[] and vice versa

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to calculate the surface area of a player using Kinect for Xbox 360 and SDK 1.8. I've ran into a small hiccup where I need to convert an `short[]` to `int[]` and vice versa. to explain more...

```
        short[] rawDepthData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
        depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(rawDepthData);
```

But I need the `rawDepthData` in `int[]` format..

Help appreciated
Many Thanks

Comment: why not simply declare `rawDepthData` as `int[]`?

Comment: You will have to _convert_ the data- you can't just copy or cast.  Use `Array.ConvertAll` or another mechanism to convert the array.

Comment: You can't map **all** ints to shorts so there will always be a chance of this failing. You'd be better off sticking to one type short or int.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I cant as `CopyPixelDataTo` can only copy to a `short[]`

Comment: @DStanley Thats what I was intending to but cant find the mechanism for it.

Comment: @envyM6 `Array.ConvertAll` is one mechanism.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Just use a loop - for this conversion, it will probably be faster than using `Array.ConvertAll()` (which uses its own loop, and a delegate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something that you probably want to be as fast as possible, you might want to consider just writing your own loop to copy the `short[]` array into a new `int[]` array, for example:

```
public static int[] Convert(short[] input)
{
    int[] result = new int[input.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
        result[i] = input[i];

    return result;
}
```

Here's how you'd convert back. IMPORTANT: This assumes that the `int` values will each fit into a `short`. If they do not, they will be truncated and the values will change!

```
public static short[] Convert(int[] input)
{
    short[] result = new short[input.Length];

    unchecked
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
            result[i] = (short) input[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

(Note: When comparing the performance of this with that of `Array.ConvertAll()`, you must compile this code as a RELEASE build - otherwise you'd be comparing a debug build with a release build.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq:

```
var myIntData = rawDepthData.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
```

Or simply a `for` loop (which would be MUCH faster), if you aim for performance:

```
var myIntData = new int[rawDepthData.Length];
for(var i = 0; i < rawDepthData.Length; i++)
   myIntData[i] = rawDepthData[i];
```

If striving for performance, I'd use the `for` method, and also have my `int[]` array ready (and not allocate one new every time), since the raw depth data length is more likely not changing

Another more performant way to do it would be using `unsafe`, pointers and unrolling the loop:

```
unsafe static void CopyData(short[] input, int[] output)
{
    fixed(short* pt1 = input)
    fixed(int* pt2 = output)
    {
        short* pt1f = pt1;
        int* pt2f = pt2;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length/8; i ++)
        {
            *pt2f = *pt1f;
            *(pt2f + 1) = *(pt1f + 1);
            *(pt2f + 2) = *(pt1f + 2);
            *(pt2f + 3) = *(pt1f + 3);
            *(pt2f + 4) = *(pt1f + 4);
            *(pt2f + 5) = *(pt1f + 5);
            *(pt2f + 6) = *(pt1f + 6);
            *(pt2f + 7) = *(pt1f + 7);
            pt1f += 8;
            pt2f += 8;
        }
    }
}
```

While a bit ugly for the .NET framework, this should be the fastest way. I've actually made some profiling (not scientific by any means), and on some of my tests, with different array sizes and loops, I get a ~30-40% increase on the `unsafe` one (notice that without unrolling the loop, I get a very marginal performance increase of around 5-10%, depending on array size)... this actually assumes the length is divisible by 8, you can adjust or check as necessary :-)

### Profiling

<sup>* just because I was curious and had a bit of time right now</sup>

Since I was curious, this is the result of some of my profilings over different methods (100% is the fastest method, "iterations" is the number of times I make the copy operation... I verify the data but that's outside the performance calculation), also, the arrays are pre-allocated (not allocated on every iteration). I left Linq out since it was WAY slower.

1. 100,000 iterations with array length of 80,000

> Unsafe unrolled: 100% - 00:00:02.5536184
>
> Simple for() loop: 70,88% - 00:00:03.6024272
>
> foreach(...): 59,24% - 00:00:04.3105598
>
> Unrolled for(): 38,26% - 00:00:06.6739715

2. 1,000,000 iterations with array length of 8,000

> Unsafe unrolled: 100% - 00:00:02.3733392
>
> Simple for() loop: 67,70% - 00:00:03.5055304
>
> foreach(...): 55,00% - 00:00:04.3149544
>
> Unrolled for(): 39,53% - 00:00:06.0041744

3. 10,000 iterations with array length of 800,000

> Unsafe unrolled: 100% - 00:00:02.5565005
>
> Simple for() loop: 73,69% - 00:00:03.4688333
>
> foreach(...): 59,75% - 00:00:04.2783304
>
> Unrolled for(): 39,46% - 00:00:06.4778782

I'm actually pretty surprised that the safe "unrolled" `for` is the most expensive method... thinking about it, it makes sense, but at first sight (at least to me, coming from an x86 assembly background where unrolling loops for performance was pretty common back in the days) I'd have never said so. I also didn't expect `foreach` to be all that much slower than a simple `for`.

Comment: I'll add note that `for` is definitely much faster

Comment: Also note that Cast() is in the his case more appropriate and faster than Select ()

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I had suggested `Cast` (see the edit history), but it won't work to convert a `short` to an `int`, `Cast` does boxing and unboxing, and a boxed object can't be unboxed to a different type... it'll throw an `InvalidCastException`

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I will be back to computer I will check its implementation, I see no need for boxing. Pretty surprising!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : it's mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1684514/68972)

Comment: Thank you for the reference,  you saved me the time to check on my own. Good catch with unsafe unrolled loop