# Why Enumerable.Cast raises an InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

If I can implicitly cast an integer value to a double, like:

```
int a = 4;    
double b = a;
// now b holds 4.0
```

Why can I not do this:

```
int[] intNumbers = {10, 6, 1, 9};    
double[] doubleNumbers2 = intNumbers.Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

I get a "Specified cast is not valid" `InvalidCastException` exception.

Doing the opposite (casting from double to int) results in the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Small point of pedantry on the "and vice versa" - the conversion from double to integer is explicit, not implicit.

Comment: removed this "pedantry" point. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Puzzling Enumerable.Cast InvalidCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Well, you have incorrect expectations of `Cast`, that's all - it's meant to deal with boxing/unboxing, reference and identity conversions, and that's all. It's unfortunate that the documentation isn't as clear as it might be :(

The solution is to use `Select`:

```
doubleNumbers2 = intNumbers.Select(x => (double) x).ToArray();
```

Comment: great. It works to me. In fact as you have mentioned, the documentation is not clear about it. The documentation says "Converts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type". But reading foward, I realize that the IEnumerable.Cast<> is used to enable the standard query operators to be invoked on non-generic collections.

Tks!

Comment: Cast performed value type and user defined conversions prior to Visual Studio 2008 SP1, when this behavior was removed: "Queries over non-generic collections now use standard C# cast semantics. " http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd310284.aspx

Comment: What takes more performance, IEnumerable.Cast or Select(x=>(MyClass)x)?

Comment: @Shimmy: I'd have to measure to check - I doubt that it's significant. I'd *expect* the `Cast<>` call to be very silghtly faster, but almost unmeasurably so.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, the question is if the Cast<> is an iterator function or is to be performed on the collection wrapper level (if there is such a thing at all).

Comment: @Shimmy: I don't know what you mean by "collection wrapper level" but `Cast` is a normal extension method on `IEnumerable`. In fact, thinking about it, in *some* cases `Select` will be faster - if it's a `List<int>` for example, `Cast` would have to box and unbox each element, whereas `Select` won't.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've tested the performance recently and select is faster in the most cases ( 1.000.000 runs @ 1000 iterations for both test's ).

Answer (score 9):

To add to Jon's answer cast is mainly useful for objects that implement `IEnumerable` but nothing else. Take [XmlNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx) for example. If you don't have the luxury of using `System.Xml.Linq` namespace you can use `Cast<XmlElement>` to write some nice LINQ queries against it.

```
var result = xmlNodeList
    .Cast<XmlElement>()
    .Select(e=> e.GetAttribute("A") + e.GetAttribute("B"))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: It's also useful pre-C# 4 to get something like covariance: you can convert an `IEnumerable<Cat>` to an `IEnumerable<Animal>` via `Cast`, for instance. This isn't a problem as of C# 4, of course... although you might use `Cast` to perform the reverse conversion.