# Convert int[] to double[] using Cast<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IEnumerable.Cast<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760804/ienumerable-cast)

One can implicitly convert from int to double. 
Why does "Specified cast is not valid." exception is raised here?

```
 double[] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

I have tried several "versions" of it.

P.S. I know possible solutions like:

```
 double[] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();
```

But I'm curious how Cast works => why it doesn't work in this example which looks so obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cast` is made to turn an `IEnumerable` (untyped) to an `IEnumerable<T>` (generically typed). It won't actually differently-cast any of the members.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760819/570190):

> Well, you have incorrect expectations of Cast, that's all - it's meant
>   to deal with boxing/unboxing, reference and identity conversions, and
>   that's all. It's unfortunate that the documentation isn't as clear as
>   it might be

So, you're stuck with `.Select()`.

Comment: In light of this, how does the "cast" `int x = 42; double d = (double)x;` work?

Comment: Wouldn't it me more appropriate to close this question as a duplicate instead of providing the accepted answer from the question you link to?

Comment: +1 Btw: Select is faster than Cast, tested it multiple times.

Comment: @pst: Casts like that are actually compiled as "Convert" instructions. As BFree points out, the system doesn't know to perform this conversion when you're unboxing.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this fails is because essentially you're doing this:

```
        int x = 10;
        object f = x;
        double d = (double) f;
```

The int is getting boxed into the object, and when you go to unbox it, you're trying to unbox it to a double.

More specifically, here's the implementation of Cast:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
    IEnumerable<TResult> enumerable = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (enumerable != null)
    {
        return enumerable;
    }
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    return Enumerable.CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}

private static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source)
{
    foreach (object current in source)
    {
        yield return (TResult)current;
    }
    yield break;
}
```

As you can see, it's looping through the IEnumerable and boxing each element in the source. It then tries to unbox at which point you blow up.