# Processing effective way of converting arrays from type T1 to type T2

Tags: c#, .net

I had a real scenario 5 minutes ago where I needed to turn a `Guid[]` into an `object[]`.

The dead simple and quick way out of this is to type:

```
var dataset = inputArray.Select(item => (object)item).ToArray();
```

Readable and everything, but I'm not sure it is very effective (could of course be the case that the compiler optimizes it a bit).

What would you suggest is best to go from type to type (assuming it is castable between, skipping integer parsing and the like)?

**EDIT:** `Cast<T>` extension method is of course also usable.

```
var listOfGuids = new Guid[]{Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid()};
var listOfStrings = new string[]{"foo", "bar"};

var objectListGuidsLinq = listOfGuids.Cast<object>().ToArray();
var objectListStringsLinq = listOfStrings.Cast<object>().ToArray();
var objectListStringsDirect = (object[]) listOfStrings;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of an array of value types they need to be boxed, so your method or something similar like `inputArray.Cast<object>().ToArray()` is required.

However, an array of reference types can be implicitly cast to `object[]`.

Also the `OfType` extension method is useful for filtering when you have an array of multiple types.

Comment: Guid is not considered a reference type, so for the example the array cannot be implicitly cast to object[]. I guess for value types the most efficient way is to use Select or Cast<> linq methods.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, Guid is a value type. Also, there are the `Array.CopyTo` and `Array.Copy` methods but I did a quick benchmark and didn't see any significant difference in performance over the Linq methods.

Answer (score 0):

i am thinking you are doing it correct.
please check this : [IEnumerable.Cast<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760804/ienumerable-cast)

it seems that Cast method dose note work as you expect from its name.