# Copying rows from datagridwiew to datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datarow

```
DataTable dt = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Copy();
```

After i delete rows from DataGridview I am getting error while reading dt. "DeletedRowInaccessibleException"

How can i copy not deleted rows in to datatable?

Comment: Do you need to keep changes of dt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTable gridTable = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

//you can call AcceptChanges() if you want !

//create data table with the same schema as gridTable !
DataTable dt = gridTable.Clone();

foreach(DataRow row in gridTable.Rows)
{
    if(row.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
       continue;

    //import every row from the gridTable to the new DataTable.
    dt.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Here one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You asked to not copy the Deleted rows, then you could write

```
DataTable source = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
DataTable dt = source.Rows
                     .Cast<DataRow>()
                     .Where(x => x.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                     .CopyToDataTable();
```

This solution uses the [IEnumerable extensions Cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760804/ienumerable-cast) to create a sequence of DataRows to which is applied the [Where condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) checking the RowState.
Then the sequence is rematerialized in a DataTable using [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) extension