# Down casting an array of Int[] into an array of Byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, data-conversion

Is there a simple way to downcast an array of integers into an array of bytes?
Essentially, I would like to do the following thing (which does not work as is):

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[20];
byte[] byteArray = (byte[])myInArray;
```

The reason for doing this is that in my application myIntArray is actually a byte[], but was declared as an int[]. Meaning that only the least significant byte in myIntArray is of interest.

Comment: You know that the int array contains values that will fit in a byte, but the compiler doesn't. You'll have to cast each array element to a byte.

Comment: `myIntArray is actually a byte[], but was declared as an int[]` - How did you get that to happen? P/Invoke? If so, correct the P/Invoke signature.

Comment: I wish I could, but I have to use this crappy 3rd party dll. Interestingly, their Python equivalent does not have this problem. Yes, the array of int[] only contains values between 0 and 255, which is the output from a first method. A second method however requires this output, but as a byte[] instead of the int[], lol

Comment: Can't you correct the P/Invoke signature in your C# code? But wait, if the `int` array contains values like 0x00000001, 0x00000002, 0x00000003 then it is NOT an array of bytes at all; it really is an array of ints.

Comment: How would you do that on a third party dll?

Comment: Assuming this 3rd party DLL is unmanaged, you must somewhere have a P/Invoke `DllImport` declaration. What does that look like? However, I'm thinking that what you have really is an array of `int` values (occupying 4 bytes each, but with only the lsb being non-zero), so you really can't cast it or fix it by changing the DLLImport declaration.

Comment: I'm just referring to it and including it via "using" as I would do "using System;". I then have access to its API.

Comment: Ah so it isn't unmanaged - and it really is an array of ints.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Thanks, I will stick to Jamiec's answer :-)

Comment: Yes, array of int[], that should have been declare as an array of byte[]

Comment: No, you cannot directly cast such an array. All you can do is copy the data. If performance matters, you might want to look at the SIMD (System.Numerics.Vectors) "Narrow" operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might think this would work:

```
byte[] myByteArray = myIntArray.Cast<byte>().ToArray();
```

But it doesnt - see [Why Enumerable.Cast raises an InvalidCastException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760804/why-enumerable-cast-raises-an-invalidcastexception)

You can use `Select` though to project to a new array.

```
byte[] myByteArray = myIntArray.Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
```

Live demo: https://rextester.com/KVR50332

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to do just that :-)

Comment: Nice info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using Linq [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

```
byte[] byteArray = myIntArray.Select(i=> (byte)i).ToArray();
```