# Why can't I use linq's Cast with user-defined casts but I can use it with a Select call?

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I recently had a problem using it user-defined casts (cast operator overload) alongside linq's [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) method.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819473/linq-cast-extension-method-fails-but-typeobject-works) about my problem here at SO and I also found a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) that explains it well. My problem is solved.

But something kept me wondering:

Why this doesn't work:

```
foolist.Cast<bar>(); // throws InvalidCastException
```

while this works:

```
foolist.Select(f => (bar)f).ToList(); // works fine
```

I believe that it's something related to the implementation of each method. If so, couldn't the Cast method have a similar implementation to [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) allowing it to be used with user-defined casts (since this is somewhat expected).

**Note: I'm not asking why it fails. I'm asking why the Cast method was written in a way that fails.**

Comment: This is exactly the same as the question you linked - what is new in your question vs. the one you listed?

Comment: @ReedCopsey I understand why the Cast method fails. I don't understand why it was implemented this way (since I could easy workaround it).

Comment: Can a moderator see the note I added and check that is *not* a duplicate. The linked question (that I also had linked myself in my question) explains **why**, but it doesn't explain **why it is the way it is**.

Comment: The answer you linked to explains **why** it is the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is that the `Cast` method performs the cast in a generic context

```
IEnumerable<T> Cast<T>(this IEnumerable e) {
  foreach (object cur in e) { 
    return (T)cur;
  }
}
```

The actual casting logic is verified and emitted at this exact point.  This point is in a generic function and has no knowledge of the user defined conversions for the type `T` is eventually instantiated into.  All it has access to is standard CLR style conversions.

In the second example you are doing a cast on the real type (not a generic type parameter).  Hence the C# compiler has access to all user defined conversions on that object and can insert the most appropriate one.

Comment: Couldn't `e` be _typed_ (`this IEnumerable<T> e`)?

Comment: @talles it could be typed but it wouldn't help.  The cast site would still be dealing with type parameters