# All combinations and permutations of a set of characters to a given length in c#

Tags: c#, string, combinations, permutation

I have a set of characters: "ab", I need every combinations and permutations of it to given length.
What I need sets like these if I give the length of 3:
a,
b,
aa,
ab,
ba,
bb,
aaa,
aab,
aba,
abb,
baa,
bab,
bba,
bbb

and so on.

I found a sort of good solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640224/18535919), but I think it is a bit complicated. I have found a good solution in the past but I can not find it again.

```
static int maxlength = 3;
static string ValidChars = "abc";
static void Dive(string prefix, int level)
{
       level += 1;
       foreach (char c in ValidChars)
       {
            Console.WriteLine(prefix + c);
            if (level < maxlength)
            {
                Dive(prefix + c, level);
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: That answer is easy for me to understand. What is your question?

Comment: i want a simple function that writes out or returns a list bc this answer is not a single Dive("ab", 3)  it is a weird thing what my brain couldnot simplify bc im dumb

Comment: This question might be better suited on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ However if your only problem is the required external variables, why not change the method signature to something like, `static void Dive(string validChars, int maxLength, string prefix = "", int level = 0)`? You can call it externally like `Dive("ab", 3);`, and inside the function it would just be `Dive(validChars, maxLength, prefix + c, level);`

Comment: @jeanot-zubler that was good idea, it works the way I like it to, thanks

Comment: BTW if i want to put the combinations in a list how sould i do it with this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code looks simple enough, however if you are looking for *generalized* approach which doesn't use recursion you can try something like this (frankly speaking it's *more complicated*, but can be used in *general* case):

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zXCWYG)

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<T[]> SolveMe<T>(int maxLength, IEnumerable<T> chars) {
  if (maxLength < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxLength));

  if (chars is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(chars));

  var letters = chars.Distinct().ToArray();

  if (letters.Length == 0)
     yield break;

  for (var agenda = new Queue<T[]>(new[] { Array.Empty<T>() }); 
           agenda.Peek().Length < maxLength;) {
    var current = agenda.Dequeue();

    foreach (var letter in letters) {
      var next = current.Append(letter).ToArray();

      agenda.Enqueue(next);

      yield return next;
    }
  }
}
```

Demo:

```
// All solutions as a list
List<char[]> result = SolveMe(3, "ab").ToList();

var report = string.Join(", ", result.Select(item => string.Concat(item)));

Console.Write(report);
```

Output:

```
a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa, aab, aba, abb, baa, bab, bba, bbb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using recursive techniques to generate all the combinations and permutations of the given characters. Check the below code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string characters = "ab";
        int maxLength = 3;
        var output = GenerateCombinations(characters, maxLength, "");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", output.Select(item => string.Concat(item))));
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GenerateCombinations(string characters, int maxLength, string current)
    {
        if (current.Length > 0)
        {
            yield return current;
        }

        if (current.Length < maxLength)
        {
            foreach (char c in characters)
            {
                foreach (string result in GenerateCombinations(characters, maxLength, current + c))
                {
                    yield return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output: a, aa, aaa, aab, ab, aba, abb, b, ba, baa, bab, bb, bba, bbb