# C# Casting List<ushort> to List<short>

Tags: c#, .net, collections, casting

I want to do this:

```
List<ushort> uList = new List<ushort>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<short> sList = uList.Cast<short>().ToList();
```

but I get InvalidCastException "Specified cast is not valid."

How can I cast fast and efficient the above collection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Puzzling Enumerable.Cast InvalidCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception)

Comment: @Ani: I would not consider that a duplicate because I know that you can't cast `int` to `long` (they're different sizes), but I would expect a cast from `ushort` to `short` to be possible because they're the same size. In other words, `(ushort[])(object)new short[] { 0, -1 }` is perfectly valid C#.

Comment: @Gabe: It is the same issue. `(short)((ushort)1)` is valid C# as is `(long)((int)1)` (redundant cast for clarity). The issue is to do with mixing numeric-conversions and unboxing. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Comment: I am going to point out the obvious problem of a value contained in the unsigned list being greater then the greatest value allowed by a signed short.

Comment: @Ani: `(long)((int)1)` is a conversion, while `(short)((ushort)1)` is a cast. They're the same syntax in C#, but the first performs a function call while the second doesn't (or doesn't have to).

Comment: @Gabe: The issue the OP is facing is similar to why `(short)(object)(ushort)1` will throw at run-time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<short> sList = uList.Select(i => (short)i).ToList();
```

Comment: I prefer this solution, IMO, as it's standard LINQ.

Comment: I had it implemented this way before I checked back in here, and it worked fine. I'm not sure if there's performance difference between this and using ConvertAll.

Answer (score 9):

You could use ConvertAll:

```
List<short> sList = uList.ConvertAll(x => (short)x);
```