# Cast method of LINQ behaves unexpected

Tags: c#, linq

I want to convert a string into an array of bytes. When I try this by use of the Cast-function of LINQ, I get a 'System.InvalidCastException'. Why?
Here is, what I tried:

```
var x = "hallo";
var works = x.Select(c=>(byte)c).ToArray();
var doesNotWork = x.Cast<byte>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# ". We use tags for that purpose here on [SO].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Puzzling Enumerable.Cast InvalidCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception)

Comment: Agreed. What can I do to set this question to duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) *only* performs unboxing and reference conversions. It does *not* perform other conversions such as the built-in value type ones and user-defined conversions.

Before .NET 3.5 SP1 it actually *did* perform rather more conversions for you. I'm sure the person who performed the code review blogged about it, but I can never remember who it was. (I keep thinking it was Eric Lippert, but it wasn't.) I'll look it up.

One thing I'll say is that this could be better documented.

As it happens, this is the first puzzler in [Bill Wagner's recent video](http://www.developerfusion.com/media/123360/bill-wagner-offers-c-puzzles/).

Comment: It's here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ed_maurer/archive/2008/02/16/breaking-change-in-linq-queries-using-explicitly-typed-range-variables.aspx, and was pointed out in this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception/445497#445497

Comment: @Jason: Thanks - I don't think that's the blog post I was thinking of, but it's similar :)

Comment: I, unfortunately, did the code review that allowed the bad code to get into the world. Ed blogged about it.

Comment: @Eric: Ah, in that case maybe it was a comment in an email or something like that. Welcome back from holiday, btw.

Answer (score 4):

I guess I have to ask why you would want to perform a cast of a string value into a byte array without using an Encoding?

```
string value = "Some Value";
byte[] myBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
```

Comment: I am uncertain, which Endoding I have to use. Why UTF8?

Comment: UTF-8 is just one I picked. You can encode using any page, but .Net provides shortcuts for ASCII and UTF flavors. UTF-8 is also the most common encoding for Latin based languages.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

var works = x.ToArray().Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();

Comment: Why would you call `ToArray` first? That's *just* added overhead on top of the original already-working code.

Answer (score 0):

From [Anders Hejlsberg](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/fe6c7c84-5f99-484a-99de-b331d4c88b76/):

> Right, due to a bug (should I say unintended feature?) in the RTM
>   version of .NET 3.5 the Cast method works for *some* conversions, but
>   with unexpected semantics. For example, floating-point to integral
>   conversions use bankers rounding, whereas regular C# casts round
>   toward zero. Also, the Cast method was rather slow and inefficient in
>   .NET 3.5 RTM. All of this was fixed in SP1, and Cast now only supports
>   reference and boxing conversions as originally intended--and does so
>   efficiently.

I think the 3.5sp1 change to Enumerable.Cast is to make it work with .Net's notion of casting, which is different than the capabilities reached using c#'s casting syntax (specifically: conversions).  This makes sense as .Cast is a .net framework thing and not a c# thing.