# Extending a property and in meanwhile insert a new item

Tags: c#, .net, linq, properties, extend

This is my code:

```
var myList = myPage.News.Cast<MyNew>();
```

MyNew have somethings like 20 property (Name, Title, Date, Place, etc etc) but it miss one, the property (for example) `Tel`.

Can't recreate my whole structure (it also become from a DLL), so I'd like to faster add a property of MyNew called `Tel`, inside that list. So extend the class during the insert in a list.

Comment: You could add it as an extension method called `Tel()` to `MyNew` perhaps? No extension properties sadly.

Comment: Is the `MyNew` class sealed as if it is not you might be able to inherit from the class adding on any properties you need

Comment: Are you expecting that this property should be available on compile time so you can fere to it in a C# code or it participates in run time stuff only?

Answer (score 3):

No, but you could create an anonymous type that includes the original type plus your new column:

```
var myList = myPage.News
                   .Cast<MyNew>()
                   .Select( new { m => MyNew = m,
                                       Tel = [formula for tel]
                                }
                          );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyNewExtended: MyNew {
   public String Tel { get;set; }
}

var myList = myPage.News.Cast<MyNewExtended>();
```

(but see Chris Sinclair's comment below)

Comment: Assuming `News` is `IEnumerable<MyNew>`, the `Cast<MyNewExtended>` will fail because they _aren't actually_ objects of the subclass type.

Comment: I had no idea Cast<T>() was so tricky ("the behaviour of Cast<T>() was changed between .NET 3.5 and .NET 3.5 SP1")  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception

Comment: Just think of it like a literal type-cast to a _subclass_. It will _not_ perform any _conversion_ even if an explicit/implicit conversion exists. (but since `MyNewExtended` extends `MyNew` you wouldn't be able to write a user-defined conversion anyway)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to extend `MyNew` with a partial class like so:

```
public partial class MyNew
{
    public int Tel { get; set; }
}
```

`Tel` will then be available like any other property.

Comment: Can't use `partial` because the class is already compiled in another DLL.

Comment: Partial is just a way of splitting a class across files.  The class has to be partial in the first place.

Comment: -1 Vaze re-read how the OP is explaining his issue in his question. `partial class won't help`

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I didn't see that it was from another DLL.