# Is there a simple way to re-cast a char[] array as Int32[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I'm working on a C# program to scrub extended ASCII characters (examples are in my input string) from a series of text files. Here's what I'm running into. While I can recast the `char` as `Int32` in my `for` loop, I'm trying to see if there's any way, to re-cast the array as `Int32` values? In a perfect world, I'd like to pass an `Int32` array of  rocessing methods directly. Right now, I'm planning on just creating a method that takes the `char` array and returns an `Int32` array. Is there an easier way to do this that would be similar to the comment I've included in my code?

```
string value = "Slide™1½”C4®";
byte[] asciiValue = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);   // byte array
char[] array = value.ToCharArray();                   // char array
 /* 
    is there something like
       Int32[] int32Array = array[].ToInt32();
 */
Console.WriteLine("CHAR\tBYTE\tINT32"); 
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    char  letter     = array[i];
    byte  byteValue  = asciiValue[i];
    Int32 int32Value = array[i];
     /* 
        ... evaluate int32Value and do stuff ...  
     */
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", letter, byteValue, int32Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

My plan B:

```
private Int32[] RecastCharArray(char[] array)
{
    Int32[] int32Value ;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
         int32Value[i] = array[i];
    }
    return int32Value;
}
```

Comment: why do you want a 32bit value for the ascii character?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224360/why-are-ascii-values-of-a-byte-different-when-cast-as-int32. I need to be able to differentiate the four different characters that are showing up with a byte value of 63.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ.

```
char[] array = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3' };
int[] int32Value = array.Select(r=> (int) r).ToArray();
```

If you want to convert numeric characters to `int` like changing character `'1'` to digit `1` then you can do:

```
char[] array = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4' };
int[] intArray = array.Where(char.IsDigit)
                      .Select(r => (int) char.GetNumericValue(r))
                      .ToArray();
```

This will give you the numeric representation not the ASCII value.

Comment: I'm too slow for you guys :(

Comment: Why does Select with an explicit cast in it work, and Cast<T> does not?

Comment: @kat0r, not really sure. I thought about it first but when I tried I got the exception.

Comment: @kat0r, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/445497/961113) seems to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, was just writing my own question. That is really annoying behaviour, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ ?

```
char[] array = value.ToCharArray(); 
int[] newarray = array.Select(c => (int)c).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int[] ints = Array.ConvertAll<char, int>(chars, c => (int) c);
```