# Why are ASCII values of a byte different when cast as Int32?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I'm in the process of creating a program that will scrub extended ASCII characters from text documents. I'm trying to understand how C# is interpreting the different character sets and codes, and am noticing some oddities.

Consider:

```
namespace ASCIITest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string value = "Slide™1½”C4®";
            byte[] asciiValue = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);   // byte array
            char[] array = value.ToCharArray();                   // char array
            Console.WriteLine("CHAR\tBYTE\tINT32"); 
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                char  letter     = array[i];
                byte  byteValue  = asciiValue[i];
                Int32 int32Value = array[i];
                 //
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", letter, byteValue, int32Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output from program

```
CHAR    BYTE    INT32
S       83      83
l       108     108
i       105     105
d       100     100
e       101     101
T       63      8482      <- trademark symbol
1       49      49
½       63      189       <- fraction
"       63      8221      <- smartquotes
C       67      67
4       52      52
r       63      174       <- registered trademark symbol
```

In particular, I'm trying to understand why the extended ASCII characters (the ones with my notes added to the right of the third column) show up with the correct value when cast as `int32`, but all show up as `63` when cast as the `byte` value. What's going on here?

Comment: Wrong encoding. It's Unicode.

Comment: Well, crap. That certainly is a logical explanation. And it changes things up a bit for my programming assumptions. Time to write a new question. :)

Comment: Most likely it's due to the encoding using more than one byte per character.  When you convert it to ASCII you're only seeing the first byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASCII.GetBytes` conversion replaces *all* characters outside of ASCII range (0-127) with question mark (code 63).

So since your string contains characters outside of that range your `asciiValue` have `?` instead of all interesting symbols like `™` - its `Char` (Unicode) repesentation is 8482 which is indeed outside of 0-127 range.

Converting string to char array does not modify values of characters and you still have original Unicode codes (`char` is essentially `Int16`) - casting it to longer integer type `Int32` does not change the value.

Below are possible conversion of that character into byte/integers:

```
var value = "™";
var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value)[0]; // 63(`?`) - outside 0-127 range
var castToByte = (byte)(value[0]); // 34 = 8482 % 256
var Int16 = (Int16)value[0]; // 8482 
var Int32 = (Int16)value[0]; // 8482
```

Details available at [ASCIIEncoding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> ASCIIEncoding corresponds to the Windows code page 20127. Because ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, ASCII characters are limited to the lowest 128 Unicode characters, from U+0000 to U+007F. If you use the default encoder returned by the Encoding.ASCII property or the ASCIIEncoding constructor, characters outside that range are replaced with a question mark (?) before the encoding operation is performed.

Comment: @Gusman I'm not sure what your comment mean - sorry. Yes `™` indeed is valid character and it have Unicode code point, but it does not make it fit into ASCII range... `ASCII.GetBytes(new char[]{(char)8482})` will return `{'?'}`.