# How to calculate the sum of a huge range filtered by a predicate in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to test the performance of three solutions for the [Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) from [projecteuler.net](https://projecteuler.net/) by passing an `int.MaxValue` instead of 1000.

**First solution**:

```
    long sum = SumDivisibleBy(3) + SumDivisibleBy(5) - SumDivisibleBy(15);
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Where SumDivisibleBy is:

```
public static long SumDivisibleBy(int k, int n = int.MaxValue)
{
    long m = n / k;
    return k * (m * (m + 1) / 2);
}
```

is faster (about 27 seconds) than

**second solution**:

```
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        {
            sum += (long)i;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

The **third solution** (which is an elegant one in my opinion) is:

```
    Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1, 999)
                                .Where(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
                                .Sum());
```

but I cannot achieve this (for testing performance purpose):

```
    Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue)
                                    .Where(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
                                    .Sum());
```

because it gives me an `OverflowException` which is natural because of the nature of `int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source)`.

**My question is this:**

How can I upcast the `int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source)` to the `long Sum(this IEnumerable<long> source)` in the code below:

```
    Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue)
                                    .Where(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
                                    .Sum());
```

Comment: Using LinqPad i do not see any error message. Code in solution 3 has been executed in 0.072 sec.

Comment: @MaciejLos Look at the alternative to solution #3.

Comment: I'm curious if .Sum<Long>() would work.

Comment: @Maciej Los I was speaking about the int.MaxValue not 999.

Comment: 1. You should not output to the console within the stopwatch measurement. 2. You should run test code in a loop of as many iterations as possible to perform in a reasonable amount of time and then divide by number of iterations to get more accurate times.

Comment: @J.Steen, Ok, i missed that ;)

Comment: @T.Glatzer It does not. You can not call `Sum<long>` on an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @AndritchiAlexei, yeah... i,ve been warned by J.Steen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try projecting the filtered sequence of ints to a sequence of longs:

```
.Where(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
.Select(x => (long)x)
.Sum()
```

Note that `.Cast<long>()` looks more elegant but [won't work for this kind of conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception).

Comment: Alternatively, `.Select<int, long>(i => i)` will also work, making the cast implicit.

Comment: The Compiler would also determine `var sum = Enum.Sum(i => (long)i)` as Int64, which would hide the select. But I did not test it in runtime.

Comment: @T.Glatzer great hint! It works: `Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue).Where(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0).Sum(x => (long)x));`. That's even better and ...elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the `Enumerable` class like below:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<long> Range(long start, long count)
    {
        for (long i = start; i < start + count; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    } 
}
```

This way you could make use of `Sum` method without having any issue, like below:

```
MyExtensions.Range(1, int.MaxValue)
            .Where(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
            .Sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for information... I tested all recommended solutions (LinqPad) and checked the time of execution.

**Method 1)** conversion with *Select* - time: **1:23.360s** (mid)

```
.Select(x => (long)x)
```

**Method 2)** Extension method - time: **02:06.768s** (slow)

```
MyExtensions.Range(1, int.MaxValue)
            .Where(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0)
            .Sum());
```

**Method 3)** suggested by T.Glatzer in comment to Ani's solution - time: **00:54.567** (quick)

```
Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue).Where(x=> x%3==0 || x%5==0).Sum(x=>(long)x);
```

***Conclusion:***
Each method is much, much slower than your **SumDivisibleBy** function, so what are the benefits of Linq solutions other than elegant code? None.

*Note:* i do not tested it in other areas such as memory usage, CPU usage, etc.

Comment: You are absolutely right, and yes I know that `SumDivisibleBy` is much faster than other (because in case of SumDivisibleBy we have O(1) complexity but in methods with LINQ we have O(n)). My question  was quite specific about **upcasting** the `.Sum()` from `int` to `long` (because I wasn't able to test for performance with an `int.MaxValue`), I **didn't ask** about benefits of one method to another.

Comment: @AndritchiAlexei, i know what you were asking about, that's why i added on the begining of my answer: "*just for information*". Cheers, Maciej