# Covariance for builtin types

Tags: c#, .net

I want to implement a `Cast` method becuase I have tons of ugly `source.Select(x => type(x)).ToArray()`. So I write a simple extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> CastConvertible<TResult>(this IEnumerable<IConvertible> source)
{
    foreach (var value in source)
    {
        yield return (TResult) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof (TResult));
    }  
}
```

But it doesn't work because of error:

> Error CS1929  'IEnumerable< int>' does not contain a definition for
>   'CastConvertible' and the best extension method overload
>   'ZEnumerable.CastConvertible< short>(IEnumerable< IConvertible>)'
>   requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable< IConvertible>'

But `int` is `IConvertible` while we know that `IEnumerable<out T>` is covariant so `IEnumerable<DerivedType>` could be converted to `IEnumerable<BaseType>`.

Here is an example:

```
int a = 10;
int[] b = {a};

IConvertible aa = a;
IEnumerable<IConvertible> bb = b;
```

So I should remove `where` constraint to be able to use this method but in this case I lose compile-time checking that type can be converted.

Why covariance doesn't work in this case?

---

I'm not using `Enumerable.Cast<T>` because it doesn't work for builtin types. For example `short[] shorts = new int[] {1, 2, 3}.Cast<short>().ToArray();`
will throw an exception, because `Cast` method uses internally non-generic `IEnumerable` so each value is boxed and then throws an exception, becuase an unboxing is only valid for exact initial type.

Comment: Why are you not using `IEnumerable.Cast<T>`?

Comment: Because it doesn't work in this case. Simple example `short[] shorts = new int[] {1,2,3}.Cast<short>().ToArray()`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception) thread

Comment: Jon Skeet has an excellent explanation of that behavior on his answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type

Comment: Instead of `CastConvertible<TResult>(this IEnumerable<IConvertible> source` use `this IEnumerable<TSource> source` use `CastConvertible<TSource,TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source`. Although this will work, eg. `var shorts = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.CastConvertible<int, short>().ToArray();`, the result of `ChangeType` still needs unboxing and incurs a performance penalty. You can add `where TSource :IConvertible` if you want to ensure only IConvertible types are used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Peformance is not an issue here, I just wanted to clear API for a function, and in this case we require to specify both source and target types. I wanted to avoid it. But it seems that it's another language limitation and nothing to do here.

Comment: @Victor thanks, I googled this behaviour but didn't find this very article which is what I required. As i said there is nothing to do, no elegant solution exist. The only way to do a fast-and-elegant solution it's just use T4 templates and generate an overload for each primitive type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Variance applies only to **reference** types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

So the key point in your question is not the **builtin**, but **value** type.

One way to resolve the issue is to add another generic argument to your extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T, TResult> CastConverible<TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : IConvertible
```

But it will not be so useful because the caller will need to specify both generic types, not only the `TResult`.

Another way is to define your extension method on non generic `IEnumerable` (similar to `Cast`)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> CastConverible<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
```

But this way you cannot constrain it to `IConvertible` elements.

The best option I see is to replace you method with two new extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<IConvertible> AsConvertible<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : IConvertible
{
    return source as IEnumerable<IConvertible> ?? source.Select(item => (IConvertible)item);
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> ConvertTo<TResult>(this IEnumerable<IConvertible> source)
{
    return source as IEnumerable<TResult> ?? 
        source.Select(item => (TResult)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(TResult)));
}
```

The sample usage will not be so concise, but still fluent:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
var b = a.AsConvertible().ConvertTo<byte>();
```

Comment: Why not just `a.Cast<IConvertible>().ConvertTo<byte>()`?

Comment: @drowa OP wanted the method to appear only to enumerables of types that implement `IConvertible` (note the `where T : IConvertible` constraint). While your suggestion allows to be called on any enumerable and get a runtime exception if called on wrong type. i.e. the difference is compile vs run time verification.