# Why does char[].Cast<int> raise a cast exception?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is the code. It's simple enough.

```
  var text = "abcdef";
  var c1 = text.Cast<int>().ToArray(); // either this one
  var c2 = text.ToCharArray().Cast<int>().ToArray(); // or this one
```

It raises an invalid cast exception in either case. Why?

For bonus marks, what's the simplest way to do what I'm obviously trying to do, if this is not it?

---

So, the code I'm actually going to write it this:

```
  var c3 = text.Select(c=>(int)c).ToArray();
```

Which works fine.

Comment: Actually I'm not at all sure it's obvious... maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int

Comment: For bonus points for your question: what is it what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: you want an array of ascii codes?

Comment: Actually interesting. Why `Enumerable.Cast` fails? The [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365,references) is `foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;` but this cast from `char` to `int` should work.

Comment: `Cast<T>()` is not used to *convert*, use `Select()`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It is not `char` to `int` cast. It is `object` to `int` cast.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Nothing iteresting if you notice that `Cast` is defined for `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. We all know that boxed value can be unboxed only to the original type.

Comment: @MongZhu The point was that `IEnumerable` is operating on `object` (forcing value types to be boxed).

Comment: I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4142) with the relevant pieces on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_Cast__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: thanks. It's clearly a lack of documentation

Comment: It is highly unlikely they want to change the underlying operation as hunting for the relevant cast operator is going to incur lots of changes, possibly through reflection. It is **much** more likely they want to simply change the documentation to reflect the actual implementation.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: they won't do that, it's a documentation issue. The cast from object to something else what the underlying boxed value is willl fail even if there was an explicit cast. E. Lippert explains why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317455/why-does-char-castint-raise-a-cast-exception#comment83620884_48317659

Comment: What I meant was that if the documentation is in fact documenting what the method was supposed to do then actual conversion/casting must be done, which is a huge undertaking. The unbox-from-object part of the current implementation is an implementation detail, albeit an important one and would have to be thrown out if actual casting/conversion was to be performed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks Tim. I looked, but I didn't find. Actually, this one is probably better reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [source code of `Cast`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs). When you use `Cast` you are iterating the collection as an array of `object`, and then it is converted to the desidered type. So the generated code (for the `Cast` part) for the code you post is:

```
foreach (object item in text)
{
    yield return (int)item;
}
```

Of course, this will generate an exception as documented [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/) (link provided by [Rawling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215380/rawling) in the comments, thank you).

To reproduce this you can try this code (you will get the same error):

```
var myChar = 'c';
object myObject = myChar;
int myInt = (int)myObject; // Exception here
```

---

### A possibile solution

**Disclaimer:** tested only with the given example and of course really slow).

You could make your own `Cast` method using `Convert.ChangeType`.

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MyCast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        var type = typeof(TResult);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return (TResult)Convert.ChangeType(item, type);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as you would do with `Cast`.

```
var c1 = text.MyCast<int>();
```

Comment: So you canot cast a boxed char to `int`?! Where is it documented?

Comment: @TimSchmelter https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/ (or the C# spec says `An unboxing operation to a non_nullable_value_type consists of first checking that the object instance is a boxed
value of the given non_nullable_value_type,and then copying the value out of the instance` ... `For an unboxing conversion to a given non_nullable_value_type to succeed at run-time, the value of thesource
operand must be a reference to a boxed value of that non_nullable_value_type.`)

Comment: No.  You must unbox the value first, before converting it.  Conversions between primitive types (like char => int) compile to special runtime routines.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find where it is documented, but LINQ's `Cast` [uses a cast via `object`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,152b93d25e224365,references), essentially performing

```
int i = (int)(object)c;
```

on each character in your string.

It *boxes* the `char`, and then tries to *unbox* it as an `int`, which [isn't possible](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/).

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I should have thought of that (except I couldn't believe it would be that dumb). Well picked! This verges on being a bug -- it certainly isn't documented anywhere I can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "abcdef";
var intText = text.Select(c => (int)c);
```

This is something you can start with to convert each char to `int` in a form of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: But the question remains, why does `Enumerable<Cast>` fail? It uses the same code

Comment: The question isn't "how can I do this?", the question is "why does this method, which seems to be documented to do exactly this, fail to do this?".

Comment: So I answered the "*For bonus marks, what's the simplest way to do what I'm obviously trying to do, if this is not it?*" part. The other part is somehow answered in other answers