# Can an array of decimal values be assigned to a List of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Is is possible to assign an array of decimal values to a list of integers? Let's say I have an array like `decimal[]` decemalNumbers and a list of integers like List intNumbers.
So can I do the assignment like `intNumbers = decemalNumbers.ToList()`?

How Can I do an explicit conversion? Is it possible?

Comment: List is like List < int> intNumbers.

Comment: Only if you cast your `decimal` to an `int`; however you will loose your decimal places.

Comment: Was just about to mention that

Comment: Use something like `intNumbers = decemalNumbers.Select(c => (int) c).ToList()`

Comment: @Evk yeah...this has worked. thanks

Comment: As suggested I tried this and it worked.

Comment: decimal[] decimalNumbers = new decimal[3];
            decimalNumbers[0] = 454545.54M;
            decimalNumbers[1] = 454556.23M;
            decimalNumbers[2] = 454556.89M;
            List<int> bagTagResult = decimalNumbers.Select(c => (int)c).ToList();
            foreach (var item in bagTagResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple LINQ solution:

```
decimal[] decimalNumbers = {1.11m,5.22m,3.25m,4.66m,9.13m};
List<int> integerNumbers = decimalNumbers.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

Output:

```
integerNumbers[0]=1
integerNumbers[1]=5
integerNumbers[2]=3
integerNumbers[3]=5
integerNumbers[4]=9
```

Comment: Yes...it's similar to what @Evk suggested

Answer (score 0):

try like this , to convert it to int

```
// obj is decimal array or list
IEnumerable<int> result = obj.select(d=> decimal.ToInt32(d));
```

Comment: Using `Cast<int>` on decimal[] will result in an InvalidCastException when you start iterating. You have to use an explicit cast such as in `Select(d => (int)d)`. For an explanation why Cast does not work see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445471/puzzling-enumerable-cast-invalidcastexception).

Comment: @mikez - let me try at my end ...because cast is ment for casing value

Comment: @PranayRana `Cast<T>` first boxes the value to `object`, before casting it, which then causes the `InvalidCastException`.